# How can I position one div to the right of two others?

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to position three elements inside a `div` and I'm having some trouble.

Two of these elements need to be stacked to the left and one floated to the right.

Placing `#three` above the other content and floating it to the right allows it to appear in the correct location. However, once my media queries kick in on small screens and those three elements jump to 100% width it appears in the incorrect order.

How can I position `#three` so it appears at the same height at `#one` and `#two` without having to re-order them?

I cannot tuck `#two` inside `#one` as it is not relevant to the `address` tag.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
}

#one, #two {
  width: 40%;
}

#three {
  float: right;
  }

#one {
  background-color: green;
  }
#two {
  background-color: blue;
  }
#three {
  background-color: orange;
  }
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <address id="one">
    <p>text text text <br> text text <br> text</p>
    </address>
  <div id="two">
    <p>text text text text </p>
    </div>
  <nav id="three">
    <p>text text text <br> text text <br> text</p>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: did you try to put "float" on both of your divs.... they will display next to each other... then use "clear" on next element to put it under your floating ones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you position `#three` absolutely? When your media queries kick in, then position it back at relative. http://jsfiddle.net/L0v8ozjq/

Answer (score 0):

You had to put the `#one` and `#two` into another container. I've added a `.left` and `.right` class for the floats.

The definition of a float, according to the W3C:

> A float is a box that is shifted to the left or right on the current
>   line. The most interesting characteristic of a float (or “floated” or
>   “floating” box) is that content may flow along its side (or be
>   prohibited from doing so by the “clear” property). Content flows down
>   the right side of a left-floated box and down the left side of a
>   right-floated box.

So what happens is that `#three` floats right, but is put down to the right side of `#two`. Also `#two` needed a `clear: left` because the float property displays every float in-line. The `clear: left` is like a new row. When the width of the browser becomes smaller, `#three` floats under `#two` since it follows the float rule.

See my fiddle for the result: http://jsfiddle.net/54ej9wt5/

Answer (score 0):

put max width of #div3 as 20%.